# Count of tickets for each and every user using sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

My table `workitem` has the columns `ticketNo`, `owner`, `status`, `subject` and `message`, and I want number of tickets per user in each and every status. My query returns the following results:

```
  Owner    Status       Count      
  Daniel   Open         2
  Daniel   InProgress   5
  Daniel   Completed    10
  Moorthi  Open         2
  Moorthi  InProgress   2
  Moorthi  OnHold       5
  Moorthi  Competed     7
```

But I am looking for results like:

```
  Owner    Status       Count
  Daniel   Open         3
  Daniel   InProgress   5
  Daniel   Completed    10
  Daniel   OnHold       0
  Daniel   Review       0
  Moorthi  Open         2
  Moorthi  InProgress   2
  Moorthi  OnHold       5
  Moorthi  Competed     7
  Moorthi  Review       0
```

My query:

```
select owner, Status, COUNT(status) from workitems 
group by Owner, Status order by  Owner, Status
```

Comment: I have tried it in a sqlfiddle. sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a7345/6

Answer (score 0):

SELECT owner, sum([Open]) as [Open], sum([Closed]) as [Closed], sum([InProgress]) as [InProgress], sum([Review]) as [Review]
FROM workitem
PIVOT(count(status)
      FOR status IN ([Open], [Closed], [InProgress], [Review])) AS PVTTable
group by owner

sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa4d0/30

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

SELECT
    TEMP1.owner,
    TEMP1.status,
    COUNT(w.subject)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT owner,
        TEMP.status
    FROM
        #workitem
    CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT 'Open' AS status
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 'InProgress'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 'Completed'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 'OnHold'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 'Review') AS TEMP
) AS TEMP1
LEFT JOIN
    #workitem w
ON
    TEMP1.owner = w.owner AND
    TEMP1.status = w.status
GROUP BY
    TEMP1.owner,
    TEMP1.status
ORDER BY
    TEMP1.owner